# Unknown space in angular component

Tags: html, angular, css

I've just started learning Angular 6. 
I created a simple Angular app in which I created a header-component.

**header.component.html**

```
<header class="head">
  <div class="header-background">
  </div>
</header>
```

**app.component.html**

```
<app-header></app-header>
```

**header.component.css**

```
* {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.head {
    height: 90vh;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    border: 1px solid green;
}

.header-background {
    background-color: rgba(128, 128, 128, 0.09);
    height: 80%;
    width: 90%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

When I run ng serve I see a white spacing at the top, left and right I'm not sure what it is. I have double checked `padding` and `margin` is **0px**.

I'm adding a screenshot [image: screenshot].

**Here you can see that there is white space at the top, left and right outside my `.head`'s border**. I have also added bootstrap@3.7.7 in my project file.

Pls provide the solution and also state the reason why I'm facing this problem.

This is the space I'm talking about.

[image]

Comment: `height: 80%;
    width: 90%;` it's this and you made the element to be centred. Follow the colors you have a green border and a grey background

Comment: I think @TemaniAfif is right

Comment: @TemaniAfif I'm talking about the space outside the green border.

Comment: any element should from the top left of the browser. if it doesn't have any margin.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My guess would be that you don't have configured style encapsulation in your header component. If you have styles in your components stylesheet file, by default those files are only applied to your component template. This means that your first rule does not apply to the body of the page, but only for every tag in your header component.

If this the case you can fix it in two different ways:

1. Move your first style (the one with the `*` selector) into your applications main style.css.
2. Change your component so it sets view encapsulation to none.

To do the change the view encapsulation, you simply need to add one line to your component decorator:

```
@Component({
    selector: '...',
    template: '...',
    styleUrls: ['...'],
    encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
})
```

The import should be

```
import {ViewEncapsulation} from '@angular/core';
```

Answer (score -1):

It's because you have declared that your `.head` should have a height equal to 90% of the screen height and that `.header-background` should have 80% height of that 90%. Also, you are setting the width to 90% of the screen width. The default background color of the body is white. So in fact, it's not any margin or padding that you see. Try setting 100% height and width if you want the gray area to cover the whole page.

Comment: No i do not want the grey area to cover the page. I'm talking about the space outside the green border.

Comment: Add margin: 0 to body in the global styles.css file, not in header.component.css